# Capture Event hover and stay versus passing by

Tags: jquery, mousehover

Is there a way to capture a mouse hover and stay (for a while) event but not if the mouse is passing by the element. So the event will be fired only when you hover and stay.

Comment: you can trigger a `setTimeout` with the `onmouseover` event and clear it (if needed) `onmouseout`. Try it and tell us if you need more help (with your code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) to create a delay before executing whatever code you need to, and [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) to cancel the timer when the mouse leaves the element:

```
var timer;
$("#example").mouseover(function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("time passed");
    }, 1000); 
}).mouseout(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);  
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/DQNSb/9/) of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a plugin exists for it. I use it in almost all of my hover code:

- [jQuery HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin designed just for this.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a javascript timer, starts counting when mouse over.
When the mouse leaves, stop the timer. The timer can trigger an event, if the mouse off/leave never occurs, the timer will set off your hover/stay function.

Probably JQuery pluggins for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

On mouseenter a timer will start after 500ms yourFunction will be call
If the user leave before your delay, the timer will be cleared, so the function won't be called.

```
yourElement.live({
    mouseenter: function() {
        t=setTimeout(function(){ yourFunction() }, 500); 
    }, mouseleave: function() {
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
});
```

Hope this help :)